# Best NHibernate multithreading pattern?

Tags: multithreading, nhibernate, session, thread-safety

As we know, NHibernate sessions are not thread safe. But we have a code path split in several long running threads, all using objects loaded in the initial thread.

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    var parent = session.Get<T>(parentId);
    DoSthWithParent(session, parent);
    foreach (var child in parent.children)
    {
        parallelThreadMethodLongRunning.BeginInvoke(session, child);
        //[Thread #1] DoSthWithChild(child #1) -> SaveOrUpdate(child #1) + Flush()
        //[Thread #2] DoSthWithChild(child #2) -> SaveOrUpdate(child #2) + Flush()
        //[Thread #3] DoSthWithChild(child #3) -> SaveOrUpdate(child #3) + Flush()
        // -> etc... changes to be persisted immediately, not all at the end.
        EndInvoke();
    }
    DoFinalChangesOnParentAndChildren(parent);
    session.Flush();
}
```

}

One way would be a session for each thread, but that would require the parent object to be reloaded in each. Plus, the final method is also doing changes on the children and would run in a StaleObjectException if another session changed it meanwhile, or had to be evicted/reloaded.

So all threads have to use the same session. What is the best way to do this?

1. Use save queue in initial thread (thread safe implementation), which is polled in a loop (instead of EndInvoke()) from the main thread. Child threads can insert NHibernate objects to be saved by the main thread.
2. Use some callback mechanism to save/flush objects in main thread. Is there something similar possible to UI thread callback in WPF, Control.Invoke() or BackgroundWorker?
3. Put Save/Flush accesses into lock(session)  blocks? Maybe dangerous, because modifying the NHibernate objects might change the session, even if not doing a Save()/Flush().
4. Or should I live with the database overhead to load the same objects for separate sessions in each thread, evict and reload them in the main thread and then do changes again? [edit: bad "solution" due to object concurrency/risk of stale objects]

Consider also that the application has a business logic layer above NHibernate, which has similar objects, but sends it's property values to the NHibernate objects on it's own Save() command, only then modifying them and doing NHibernate Save()/Flush() immediately.

Edit:
It's important that any read operation on NHibernate objects may change the session - lazy loading, chilren collection change under certain conditions. So it is really better to have a business object layer on top, which synchronizes all access to NHibernate objects. Considering the database operations take only a minimum time of the threads (mainly occasional status settings), and most is for calculations, watching, web service access and similar, the performance loss by data layer synchronization is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The session object is not thread safe, you can't use it over different threads. The SaveOrUpdate in your sepperate threads will most likely crash your program or corrupt your database. However what about creating the data set you want to update and do the SaveOrUpdate actions in your main thread (were your session is created)?

> You should observe the following practices when creating NHibernate
>   Sessions: • Never create more than one concurrent ISession or
>   ITransaction instance per database connection.
>
> • Be extremely careful when creating more than one ISession per
>   database per transaction. The ISession itself keeps track of updates
>   made to loaded objects, so a different ISession might see stale data.
>
> • The ISession is not threadsafe! Never access the same ISession in
>   two concurrent threads. An ISession is usually only a single
>   unit-of-work!

Comment: OK, that's what I knew and what's also in my options. My question is now how to best save objects in a safe way. I saw some posts here on this topic, recommending the multi-session approach (one per thread), but that doesn't look good for me, due to DB overhead and StaleObject problems by concurrent acccess. So I likely need a Save function in the main thread, which can be called from the child threads. See Option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if I understand correctly, different threads may be updating the same objects. In that case, nHibernate or not, you're performing several updates on the same objects concurrently, which may lead to unexpected results.
You may want to tweak your design a bit to ensure that an object can be only updated by (at most) a single thread.

Now, assuming your flow may include having the same threads reading the same data (but writing different data), I'd suggest using different sessions- one per thread, and utilizing [2nd level cache](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate);
2nd level cache is kept at the `SessionFactory` (rather than in the `Session`) level, and is therefore shared by all session instances.